# RecyclerView adapter's method holder.getAdapterPosition() get wrong values after scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using a RecyclerView to show a list of TextViews. I want the TextViews in positions 0,1,2,3 and 4 to have a colored square. This is my code:

```
   @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);

        if(holder.getAdapterPosition()==0) {

            holder.lytColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 201, 8));
           
        } else if(holder.getAdapterPosition()==1) {

                holder.lytColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(242, 157, 32));
                 
        }else if(holder.getAdapterPosition()==2) {
            holder.lytColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(177, 134, 66));
            
        }else if(holder.getAdapterPosition()==3) {

            holder.lytColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(123, 102, 72));
             
        }else if(holder.getAdapterPosition()==4){
                holder.lytColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(77,72,69)); 

        }
   }
```

It works:

[image]

The problem is that when I scroll down other TextViews also have colors:

[image]

I've used Log.e("test", getAdapterPosition()) to see the position, and it showed the expected value, the item's position in the ArrayList.

In my cellphone it follows the next pattern: 5 colored, 10 colorless, 5 colored, 10 colorless...

I've tested the app in other cellphone with a bigger screen and the pattern changes, 5 colored, 13 colorless, 5 colored, 13 colorless...

So I assume that the number of items that can be displayed on the screen is related to the problem.

PS: I've already tried using position parameter

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried using `getLayoutPosition()` ?

Comment: try this getOldPosition()

Comment: thanks, but those methods didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right! Position in the adapter will recycle it's in adapter's nature.

What you can do is take one variable in your model let's say colourId. Than assign the value to it when you add to the list. Say for example colourId = 1,2,3 and so on.

and get that value in the adapter like below

```
mValues.get(position).getCoulourId();
```

than Apply your if conditions on that value.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But I still wondering why the position is correct in the log message but not in the if conditions